# Python: why does my code keep telling me the answer is wrong when its not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input, equals

```
import random

d = {}
with open('StatesCapitals.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split(',')
        d[key] = value



HI = random.choice(list(d.keys()))
print(HI)

answer = (d[HI])

print (answer)

StudentAnswer = (input('Type your answer: '))

if answer.lower() == StudentAnswer.lower():
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Wrong.')
```

This will print out a randomly selected state from my file and also print out the capitol for that state which is the answer to the question. I always receive "wrong" from my else statement no matter if i type the correct answer or not and I cant seem to figure out why.

[example of what my StatesCapitals.txt looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ygMU.png)

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs(including the file)? As an aside, you don't need to random.choice the list's keys, you can just do `answer = random.choice(d)`.

Comment: You probably have some extra whitespace, try `if answer.strip().lower() == StudentAnswer.strip().lower()`

Comment: We all write code that doesn't behave the way we expect. As you learn to program, you just have to accept this fact. You also need to learn how to debug your code to find the flaws and fix them. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code. I use these techniques daily to figure out problems in code I wrote (or code someone else wrote). They are a critical part of your early education as a budding programmer.

Comment: The values have a trailing newline (`\n`), which is causing the mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating through a file returns a string with a newline at the end, so you have to remove it with `.strip()`. You should replace the 1st line in the loop with `key, value = line.strip().split(',')`.

As an aside, you don't need to `random.choice` the list's keys, you can just do `answer = random.choice(d)`.

Comment: Thank you, changing it to key, value = line.strip().split(',') fixed my issue. It was very simple I just didn't consider it.